# Can not install postgres in ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, installation

I tried to install postgresql using the following command

```
apt-get install -t squeeze-backports postgresql-9.1 postgresql-client-9.1 postgresql-contrib-9.1
```

but i got the following error message.

> E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
>   E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

how to fix this?

Comment: And? "*Are you root?*"

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you aren't running the command as root. Prefix it with "sudo".

```
sudo apt-get install -t squeeze-backports postgresql-9.1 postgresql-client-9.1 postgresql-contrib-9.1
```

per the error message:

> E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), **are you root?**

However, it looks like you don't understand the command, as you're running Ubuntu and Squeeze is a Debian dist. I think you need to go back to the basics and read the instructions:

- [Ubuntu help for Pg](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL).
- [PostgreSQL-supplied packages of newer versions](http://apt.postgresql.org/)

Comment: yes, thanks. but running with sudo. i got this error.    E: The value 'squeeze-backports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources

Comment: @user3275435 Then you aren't running Squeeze. What OS are you running? exactly? Why are you running this particular command - you don't understand what it does, so where'd you get it from and why?

Comment: i am new to linux environment. i do not know what is root. but i am currently working in /var/lib/dpkg

Comment: @user3275435 OK, you really need to start with some introductory guidance that sets out the very basics. Start here: https://help.ubuntu.com/, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=801404, https://help.ubuntu.com/community, https://ubuntu-manual.org/ . And remember, *read the error messages*.

Comment: @user3275435 For future questions please explain how you got to what you're asking about. Try something more like: *"I didn't know how to install PostgreSQL and I found this command (command text) on (this link) so I tried it. I don't understand the error (error message here). I'm new to all this and I'm stuck. Advice?"*

Answer (score 1):

Some other program has a lock on download operations. Have you got another terminal open or synaptic package manager or anything? Close everything and try again. You can also delete this file /var/lib/dpkg/lock if that doesnt work. Or it might be a root access issue. try running with sudo

Comment: After removing lock file i got the same issue mentioned above. and lock file is not available.

Answer (score 0):

> Simple steps to **install** **postgresql** latest version (**Believe me -- try these commends to install  *postgresql***..it will works perfectly )

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ 
precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 pgadmin3
```

> For Open Terminal of postgres

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```